# What is the default probability of [[likely]]? Is it possible to change it?

Tags: c++, attributes, language-lawyer, c++20

What is the default probability of [`[[likely]]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.likelihood)? Is it possible to change it?

Backgound: GCC has the following [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

- `long __builtin_expect(long exp, long c)`: the probability that a __builtin_expect expression is true is controlled by GCC's `builtin-expect-probability` parameter, which **defaults to 90%**.
- `long __builtin_expect_with_probability(long exp, long c, double probability)`: the last argument, **probability**, is a floating-point value in the range 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive.

What is the C++ definition of the term "likely"? 51%? 90%? What does the term "arbitrarily (un)likely" mean?

Comment: You already link to everything there is to say about it: There is no normative requirement at all and the recommended practice says "_arbitrarily more likely_", so any particular likelihood would be adequate. Probabilities like this are nothing that the standard would specify. (What do they even mean exactly?)

Comment: Re: "What do they even mean exactly?": I see it this way: example: for `if (<expr>) [[likely]]` the compiler can compute (using heuristics) probability of `expr` to be true. If this probability is greater than or equal to the default one (or to the user's specified), then the "short path" is generated. See: https://godbolt.org/z/vr6aPM1E4.

Comment: @user17732522 I deduced that GCC computed probability of `x == 1` as 33%. If we manually specify that the probability of `x == 1` is 34%, then GCC generates "short path". This 33% can be consistently (from 2 methods) deduced in https://godbolt.org/z/d3c4dsYEn. Interesting that ICC computes probability as 5%: `Prob 5%`. I don't know how exactly GCC and ICC compute probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "probability" for these things. They tell the compiler to rearrange code and tests around branches to optimize for the case where one path is more often taken than another. But that's all.

These are not everyday tools you should be tossing into every loop and `if` statement. These are micro-optimization tools that are best used when one has a clear performance target in mind and one sees that the compiler is generating sub-optimal machine code in a performance-critical section of code. Only then do you employ these tools. And even then, you need to check the generated code to see if they fixed the problem you're trying to solve.

These are compiler tweaks for cases where the compiler's usual methods of code generation around a branch does not produce optimal code. It's not about probability; it's about micro-optimization.

Here is a [quote from the paper adding this feature to the standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0479r2.html):

> Objection #1: Can this feature easily result in code pessimization?
>
> Yes, as shown by the conditional move example misusing a branch hint can definitely result in worse code with a much longer run time. **This feature is primarily meant to be used after a hotspot has been found in existing code. The proposed attributes are not meant to be added to code without measuring the impact to ensure they do not end up degrading performance.**

Emphasis added. So please do not just throw these anywhere.

One of the biggest dangers in adding these attributes by default is that the information is, conceptually, redundant. Something, somewhere decides what the likelihood of the branch actually is, and you're specifying that likelihood more directly.

Redundantly-specified information can *easily* get out-of-sync. Non-local changes to code can change the likelihood of branches, which gets the two out-of-sync. And once that happens, the attribute becomes very bad for performance.

So it's best to apply this in specific cases, with profilers handy, and with relatively mature code where the likelihood is unlikely to change.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248826/discussion-on-answer-by-nicol-bolas-what-is-the-default-probability-of-likely).

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays, most architectures have pipelines. If the processor decodes a conditional jump (which `if` is translated to) earlier than the condition is evaluated, it's permitted to continue evaluation speculatively (without actually committing the result). `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` simply directs the compiler to generate code choosing the path to take in these speculative cases. I'm not aware of any architecture that has probabilities involved here, it's definitely evaluated that way (*if* speculative evaluation is possible).

Also, sometimes you might use these against probabilities. Say you have a code optimized for a specific processor. You are aware that on the *actual* evaluation path you'll use each and every cache line in the CPU and you've identified which conditions might cause a cache line to be loaded. In this case, you'll likely want to put `[[likely]]` on the path that *doesn't* load a new cache line, regardless of probabilities: causing speculative loading to load a new line (and therefore potentially drop a line you'd still use) likely costs more than simply planning for no new cache line loads. So it's really not about probabilities, but speculative path to be taken by CPU (until the condition is evaluated).